# How to show the +/- difference using DateTime

Tags: php

I'm using DateTime to compare Timestamps. $firstDate below is 6 seconds more than $secondDate so I would like $interval to echo - 00:06. If it was the opposite then I would like + 00:06. No change should just display 00:00. Is there a way with DateTime to display the +/- change?

```
$firstdate = '00:00:06';
$seconddate = '00:00:12';

$one = new DateTime($firstdate);
$two = new DateTime($seconddate);
$interval = $two->diff($one);

if ($firstdate > $seconddate){
echo "-".$interval->format('%I:%S');
}
elseif($firstdate > $seconddate){
echo "+".$interval->format('%I:%S');
}
else{
echo $interval->format('%I:%S');
}
```

**The current code displays 00:06 instead of +00:06 in this example, but if $firstdate and $seconddate are reversed it does echo -00:06 as intended**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `if else`:

```
if ($firstdate > $seconddate){
echo "-".$interval->format('%I:%S');
}
elseif($firstdate < $seconddate){
echo "+".$interval->format('%I:%S');
}
else{
echo $interval->format('%I:%S');
}
```

Comment: I should of been able to figure that out on my own sorry. Thanks. I'll accept it soon as I can.

Comment: That's odd if it's less then I see -00:06 for example, but if it's greater I see 00:06 instead of +00:06. Example: $firstdate = '00:00:06'; $seconddate = '00:00:12'; echos 00:06 instead of +00:06

Comment: look at second elseif condition your conditional operator is wrong it should be $firstdate < $seconddate